# Apply CSS transition to an image with width: auto

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to apply a smooth transition effect when I'm enlarging an image. Usually its pretty easy but since I'm trying to enlarge image from being constrained vertically to be contained horizontally it doesn't seem to work properly.

This code doesn't seem to work... probably because of the width auto... before moving into JS territory, forcing a px height/width, I'd love to see if it's possible to solve it with just CSS. Thanks.

```js
$(".enlargeButton").click(function() {
  $(".image").toggleClass('larger');
});
```

```css
.image img {
  height: 80vh;
  width: auto;
  transition: height 600ms, width 600ms;
}

.image.larger img {
  width: 80vw;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- your HTML here -->
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `height: auto` and `width: auto`. In which dimension are you trying to enlarge the image?

Comment: Here's a starting point for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197443/emulate-object-fit-using-animatable-properties/64199774#64199774

Comment: Please provide HTML. CSS and jQuery mean nothing without it.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you are facing is that you set the classes together in your css: `image.larger img` try to seperate those to only `.larger`.

Maybe this code helps you to understand your issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=q, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .image {
        height: 80vh;
        width: auto;
        transition: 600ms ease-in-out;
      }

      .larger {
        height: 80vw;
        width: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img
      class="image"
      src="https://lelolobi.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/Test-Logo-Small-Black-transparent-1-1.png"
      alt=""
    />
    <button class="enlargeButton">Enlarge</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(".enlargeButton").click(function () {
        $(".image").toggleClass("larger");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What problem does this solve? You don't even know what the markup looks like.

Comment: Given OPs css `.image img {` and *assuming* that works, then they don't have `<img class='image' ..>` but rather `<div class='image'><img...></div>`   Does this always work in that case?